# Python - previous list elements being overwritten by new elements during while loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop, scrape

Hello I am new to Python and am trying to figure out why my list overwrites the previous elements every time a new page is loaded and scraped during the while loop. Thank you in advance.

```
def scrapeurls():
    domain = "https://domain234dd.com"
    count = 0

    while count < 10:

        page = requests.get("{}{}".format(domain, count))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        data = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'video'})

        urls = []

        for div in data:
            links = div.findAll('a')
            for a in links:
                urls.append(a['href'])
                print(a['href'])

        print(count)
        count += 1
```

Comment: move `urls` list out of the `while` loop

Comment: thanks, serious noob error

Answer (score 3):

Because you reset `urls` to an empty list in every iteration of the loop. You should move that to before the loop.

(Note, the whole thing would be better expressed as a for loop.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize the URL list before the loop. If you initialize inside the loop it sets it back to nothing every time.

Comment: Haha no I'm a beginner too I spent over an hour yesterday confused because my with statement would not open the file.  I had forgotten to type open before the ()'a.  Lol it happens to everyone.  (I hope)

Answer (score 1):

```
domain = "https://domain234dd.com"
count = 0

urls = []
while count < 10:

    page = requests.get("{}{}".format(domain, count))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    data = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'video'})

    for div in data:
        links = div.findAll('a')
        for a in links:
            urls.append(a['href'])
            print(a['href'])

    print(count)
    count += 1
```